# Serving stylesheets from a CDN in a Flask template

Tags: css, flask, jinja2, cdn

I have a simple flask application. It has flask-bootstrap installed and so I can access some CSS classes from there and my own style sheet in my static folder. However, I want to be able to add another stylesheet from a CDN in my index.html file.

I usually do something like place the following inside head tags.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Is this possible? I don't think that using the

```
{{url_for('static' )}}
```

syntax would work here and I haven't found anything online that's describing what i'm doing (or I couldn't tell).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how I do it too. And then I link to my own stylesheet after the Bootstrap CDN.

Edit: and if you use a base template that is being extended by multiple templates for sub pages you can put the head tag in the base template so it precedes all templates.

Comment: So just adding in that way should work? There's no special syntax needed to deal with the Jinja engine?